# Create log file for Android app

Tags: android, exception, logging

I want to create a log file for my Android app. I need this to debug the random crashes of the applications.

I want to create a function which always get called if there is a unhandelled exception. In the log I want the exception message. Is there any event kind mechanism which will get invoked on unhandelled exception in ANdroid?

Comment: Why is the logcat output not enough?

Comment: @Henry the app will be installed on device, there I want to troubleshoot why it crashed, by saving log to the sdcard

Comment: When the device is attached to the PC via USB you can get this information. Works even if you only connect the device shortly after the crash.

Comment: @Henry I think u are not aware of the importance of log file. Pls search the web for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UncaughtExceptionHandler` as shown below:

```
public class UncaughtExceptionHandler implements java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    String Tag;
    Context myContext;
    public UncaughtExceptionHandler(Context context, String TAG) {
        Tag = TAG;
        myContext = context;
    }  

    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        Logger.appendErrorLog(sw.toString(), Tag);
        Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, ForceClose.class);
        intent.putExtra(BugReportActivity.STACKTRACE, sw.toString());
        myContext.startActivity(intent);
        Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
        System.exit(10);
    }
}
```

Call this class in the first activity's `onCreate()` method:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler(getApplicationContext(),"FirstActivity"));
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use android [Android Acra](http://code.google.com/p/acra/)

Really good thing Please try this.

Comment: thanks, acra is great, but I want to write my code. Can u please help?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own log cat,

*when your application is installed on real android device and not connected to Eclipse to get debug details..*

Please check Tutorial :[Read & Store Log-cat Programmatically in Android](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/07/read-store-log-cat-programmatically-in.html)

also you may like to check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528626/android-issue-debug-when-phone-off/13854438#13854438) stack-overflow page I have posted solution code snip and related useful information.