# Debug android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, debugging, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, adb

I want to debug a `BroadcastReceiver` which should start its onReceive method when the action `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` is triggered. I have read several sources like

- [How to debug BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast receiver's "Force Close" crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086994/how-to-debug-boot-complete-broadcast-receivers-force-close-crashes)
- [Android adb shell am broadcast: Bad component name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171354/android-adb-shell-am-broadcast-bad-component-name)
- [How To Test BOOT_COMPLETED Broadcast Receiver In Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325920/how-to-test-boot-completed-broadcast-receiver-in-emulator)

but the all came with the solution to run

```
./adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

or

```
./adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c <CATEGORY> -n <PACKAGE_NAME>/<CLASS>
```

The first one restarts the device or the emulator but the debugger gets disconnected. The second one does not work. When I enter

```
./adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME mypackage/.BootReceiver
```

the message is

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] cmp=mypackage/.BootReceiver }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

and nothing happens. So my question is:

**Is there a way to debug a BroadcastReceiver which gets triggered when `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` occurs?**

I am using a Nexus 4 as a device and also a Nexus 4 as an emulator. My IDE is android studio with version 1.2.2.

Comment: If nothing else you can move to printf debugging-  Write statements to log and see what the values of variables are when you run it, rather than stepping through via debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **sendBroadcast()** to send broadcast manually

Add some action  ("NameofAction") to the receiver in the manifest and then manually use **sendBroadcast(new Intent("NameofAction"))** with the name you specified in the receiver element in the manifest.

and in **onReceive()** check for the action ("NameofAction").

Comment: Manually sending a Broadcast for android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED is not allowed.

Comment: I was telling create some action manually "NameofAction"  for testing purpose and add it to BOOT_COMPLETED  receiver and fire it manually.